# finding the intersections of two polar angles on a segment

Tags: geometry

You are given a point `Q` and a segment defined by end points `A` and `B`.

[image]

Given two polar angles `a` and `b` that are created by `Q`,

how can you find the two intersection points of the two lines (going through Q and having these polar angles) and the segment defined by `A`, `B`?

In the picture above it looks like the intersections are just the two segment end points, but the polar angles can be anything.

I took the above picture from another problem that I wanted to solve, which was given a point `Q` and a segment `A`,`B` find polar angles `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the points on a line $\ell$ at polar angles $a$ and $b$ relative to $Q,$
first obtain an equation for the line $\ell.$
Exactly how you go about doing *that* will depend on how the line $\ell$ was described
in the first place.
Supposing that the line was described in terms of $x,y$-coordinates, however,
in general it has an equation equivalent to
$$ px + qy = k $$
where $p,$ $q,$ and $k$ are some constant parameters.
(This form is a little more general than the usual "function of $x$" form,
$y = mx + k,$ because it can describe a vertical line.)

We can convert this equation into an equation for the line in polar coordinates
by substituting $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin\theta$ at an arbitrary
point $(x,y)$ on the line. Plugging these values into the equation above, we have
$$ p(r \cos\theta) + q(r \sin\theta) = k $$
which we can rewrite as
$$ (p \cos\theta + q \sin\theta)r = k $$
and therefore
$$ r = \frac{k}{p \cos\theta + q \sin\theta}. $$
So we see that $r$ is a function of $\theta,$ and this last equation gives
a way to compute $r$ directly from any value of $\theta.$

For example, to compute the coordinates of the point $A$ at polar angle $a,$
we set
$$ r_A = \frac{k}{p \cos a + q \sin a}. $$
The $x,y$-coordinates of this point are then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x_A &=& r_A \cos a = \frac{k \cos a}{p \cos a + q \sin a},\\
y_A &=& r_B \sin a = \frac{k \sin a}{p \cos a + q \sin a}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
If $\cos a \neq 0$ we can write
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x_A &=& \frac{k}{p + q \tan a},\\
y_A &=& x_A \tan a.
\end{eqnarray}$$
If $\cos a = 0,$ of course, $x_A = 0$ and $y_A = \frac kq.$

The coordinates of point $B$ can similarly be expressed in terms of
$\cos b$ and $\sin b.$

Note that for some values of $\theta,$ the polar equation of the line gives
a negative value of $r.$  This is perfectly legitimate; if $(r,\theta)$ are
polar coordinates of a point then $(-r,\theta + \pi)$ are polar coordinates
of the same point (and so are $(r,\theta + 2n\pi)$ for any integer $n$).
If you compute $r_A$ explicitly then of course you will know when it is negative;
if you use a formula that does not explicitly compute $r_A$
then you can tell that $r_A$ is negative if $\cos a$ and $x_A$ have
opposite signs.
If $x_A = 0$, then $r_A$ is negative if $\sin a$ and $y_A$ have opposite signs.